# Why there are 2 () in a sub signature?

Tags: .net, vb.net

Recently I asked a question and got a working answer. The code below is the working code. I have problem understand the Sub signature. Why there are two ()() for the sub. I mean I don't understand the first one `(Of Algorithm As SymmetricAlgorithm)`. Obviously the second one is for the paramater. Can you point to me where I can read more about it?

```
Public Shared Sub DecryptTo(Of Algorithm As SymmetricAlgorithm)(sourceStream As Stream, stream As Stream, password As String)
    Dim pdb = GetPassword(password)
    Using alg = Activator.CreateInstance(Of Algorithm)()
        Using trans = alg.CreateDecryptor(pdb.GetBytes(alg.KeySize / 8), pdb.GetBytes(16))
            Using cStream = New CryptoStream(sourceStream, trans, CryptoStreamMode.Read)
                cStream.CopyTo(stream)
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: It would be nice if anyone could add some simple examples as a new answer to this question even if this question has an accepted answer. I want to learn more about generics in VB but I have no good practical and easy examples of when and why I would use it. The screwdriver-example is good to just begin to understand it but it does not take me all the way. Thanks..

Comment: For what it's worth, the second example cited, a strongly typed collection, is one of the more common reasons why generics tend to be used. i.e. instead of writing one List implementation specifically for strings and another for integers, developers can write a single List implementation where the type of the objects being held can be specified as a generic type parameter *and* the compiler can enforce type safety at compile time so that only objects of the correct type are added to the collection.

Answer (score 4):

At http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w256ka79(v=vs.80).aspx
one can find a description of Generics (which is the reason for the first set of parentheses).

It starts:

> A generic type is a single programming element that adapts to perform
>   the same functionality for a variety of data types. When you define a
>   generic class or procedure, you do not have to define a separate
>   version for each data type for which you might want to perform that
>   functionality.
>
> An analogy is a screwdriver set with removable heads. You inspect the
>   screw you need to turn and select the correct head for that screw
>   (slotted, crossed, starred). Once you insert the correct head in the
>   screwdriver handle, you perform the exact same function with the
>   screwdriver, namely turning the screw.
>
> Screwdriver set as a generic tool
>
> When you define a generic type, you parameterize it with one or more
>   data types. This allows the using code to tailor the data types to its
>   requirements. Your code can declare several different programming
>   elements from the generic element, each one acting on a different set
>   of data types. But the declared elements all perform the identical
>   logic, no matter what data types they are using.
>
> For example, you might want to create and use a queue class that
>   operates on a specific data type such as String. You can declare such
>   a class from System.Collections.Generic.Queue, as the following
>   example shows.
>
> VB Public stringQ As New System.Collections.Generic.Queue(Of String)
>
> You can now use stringQ to work exclusively with String values.
>   Because stringQ is specific for String instead of being generalized
>   for Object values, you do not have late binding or type conversion.
>   This saves execution time and reduces run-time errors.

Comment: BoltClock: The request was "Can you point to me where I can read more about it?"... thus a plain old link was provided.

Comment: Yes, but at least you could give the link a title so people know have an idea what kind of page it leads to.

Comment: The problem with answers that contain only a link is they completely break if the link does. Please edit this answer to at least _summarize_ what can be found in the link, or it will need to be converted to a comment.

Comment: Description and explanation added.Enjoy

Answer (score 4):

VB.NET uses parenthesis in several different ways:

- parameter section of method declaration or method calls (same as C#)
- declaring [generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w256ka79.aspx) (equivalent of <> in C#)
- declaring and indexing [arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx) (equivalent of [] in C#)